# Redirecting 201109 to 2011/09 in nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx

I'm trying to redirect /201109/ to the directory /2011/09/, but I'm not sure how to do it. This is what I have so far in nginx.conf:

`rewrite ^/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})/(.*) http://www.domain.com/$2/$3/$4 permanent;`

That results in an error:

```
nginx: [emerg] directive "rewrite" is not terminated by ";" in /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:20
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test failed
```

Any idea what to do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the braces ("{" & "}") causing it to fail. As braces have specific meanings in Nginx, when you use them in nginx regexes, you need to enclose the regex string in double quotes.

So this should work for you:

```
rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})/(.*)" http://www.domain.com/$1/$2/$3 permanent;
```